# Spring Boot Cannot load data.sql into h2 database

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, h2

I tried to implement an example of Spring Batch processing. After starting the app, I wanted all values defined in data.sql loaded to the h2 database but it didn't work.

Here is the **application.properties** file shown below.

```
server.port=2121

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect


spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

Here is the data.sql file

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERS ;

CREATE TABLE USERS (
    "ID" BIGINT auto_increment NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "AGE" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "BIRTHDAY" DATE,
    "COUNTRY" CHARACTER VARYING(255),
    "EMAIL" CHARACTER VARYING(255),
    "FIRST_NAME" CHARACTER VARYING(255),
    "GENDER" CHARACTER VARYING(255),
    "LAST_NAME" CHARACTER VARYING(255),
    "PERSON_ID" CHARACTER VARYING(255)
);


INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (1, 22, DATE '2000-08-15', 'China', 'gspearing0@flickr.com', 'Ginnie', 'FEMALE', 'Spearing', 'fa26fa96-97d3-4e8e-856a-fdf07499e13e');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (2, 23, DATE '1999-01-25', 'Panama', 'nloynes2@woothemes.com', 'Natala', 'FEMALE', 'Loynes', '24be24e6-525f-42de-855d-52d4fef21608');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (3, 9, DATE '2013-04-15', 'Japan', 'jheino3@mayoclinic.com', 'Jard', 'MALE', 'Heino', '87cdda81-45d0-451a-a62f-f8450eae1b64');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (4, 8, DATE '2014-05-09', 'Indonesia', 'jcarlaw1@t.co', 'Jilleen', 'FEMALE', 'Carlaw', 'c722e6d5-9024-49c5-80e0-c2555f1eb9cc');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (5, 22, DATE '2000-03-18', 'Indonesia', 'rgillino6@china.com.cn', 'Rainer', 'MALE', 'Gillino', '5302a199-f313-4a24-9550-d643001d9faf');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (6, 9, DATE '2013-02-16', 'China', 'rcossans4@harvard.edu', 'Roseline', 'FEMALE', 'Cossans', '06f70b0d-2c98-4f46-b933-528499ab91b3');
```

How can I fix the issue?

Here is the example link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBatchProcessDbToCsv)

Comment: I think you missed the inizialition-mode parameter. https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-load-initial-data-on-startup.html

Comment: [9. Database Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization)

Comment: I think `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` is "not wrong" in your case

Comment: The other (`spring.sql.init.mode=always`..and more) depends on how good springboot can recognize your db as "embedded". (setting too many "attributes"/changing from default affects that)

Comment: If both fail, Try : `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true`

Comment: But also consider: spring-batch also needs/creates an own schema/db..(9.4;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

Add

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

into the `application.properties` file.